# Can't figure out difference between PRIVATE and PUBLIC on target_compile_options(...)

Tags: cmake

I am struggling about understand the differences between `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` scope on `target_compile_options` function on **CMake**.

In example: if I write `target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Wall)` what happens? And if I use `PUBLIC`?

Comment: It matters on libraries where PUBLIC means dependencies of the library will inherit the compile option. If the `main` target is an executable its most likely not a dependency of any other target.

Comment: I understand. So it is only about how options propagates through dependencies. So if it had been a library and had been a dependency of a main executable, this one would inherit that option, right?

Comment: If main was a library and some other target depended on it the PUBLIC would mean inherit. PRIVATE would mean don't inherit this setting.

Comment: So i.e. target_compile_options(library PUBLIC -Wall) and target_llink_libraries(main PRIVATE/PUBLIC library), main inherits -Wall option, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. This is the same way `target_include_directories(library PUBLIC somefolder)` is inherited when you use `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE/PUBLIC library)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the CMake doc here:

> Each of the commands has a `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` mode. The `PRIVATE` mode populates only the non-`INTERFACE_` variant of the target property and the `INTERFACE` mode populates only the `INTERFACE_` variants. The `PUBLIC` mode populates both variants of the respective target property. Each command may be invoked with multiple uses of each keyword:

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements

Answer (score 0):

The mode doesn't really make a difference for compile options specified on executable targets. But for library targets, it does matter. `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE` are two different things. `PRIVATE` means that the compile option(s) applies only to the target you specify the compile option(s) on. `INTERFACE` means that the compile option(s) applies to targets that link to the target you specify the compile option(s) on. `PUBLIC` is like a shorthand for specifying as both `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC`.

I'd say specifying `-Wall` with `INTERFACE` (or `PUBLIC`, by extension) is an... iffy choice. Users of your library might not like that. If nobody is ever going to use your library except your own project, then sure- do whatever you want. If you want some conservative-ish and not very controversial advice, use `INTERFACE` when you basically *know* that targets that link to the target will want (essentially need) that compile option to function properly. For example, say your target's public headers need to be parsed as utf8, in which case it might make sense to put `/utf-8` as an `PUBLIC` compile option when the compiler is MSVC.